# What's the name of this kind of system?

Tags: web, system, intranet

i'm about to start a project for sharing files, announcements,  and other stuff between branches of a company, it must be a web based system, with all the layers as profile management, employee communication, etc... What i don't know is what's the name of this kind of systems? It's a web based system wich will only allow access to the company's personnel(still don't know how to do that - help please), and must connect the different branches.

Comment: A generic name might be a *web portal*. And if you're looking for help with *access to the company's personnel*, you'll need to explain that (it's a vague statement - I assume you really mean access to some specific personnel data of which you haven't specified type or location) and show some code to ask a question about.

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for a term such a Corporate/Enterprise Intranet http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intranet or even something like a Corporate Workspace. Essentially, this would be served from an internal web server intended to only function internally and not visible outside the Corporate/Enterprise network.

Comment: @lurker Should i move this question to other community?, the only ones that will have access to the system will be the company, anyone outside the company will not know about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're making an Intranet Software or kind of that.

Look here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_social_software

Software examples
Specific social software tools which programmers have adapted for enterprise use include:

- wikis
- social bookmarking
- social search
- Web Content Management System
- instant messaging
- file sharing

So, you are doing a profile management, file sharing...it looks like an intranet.

Example of intranet: http://www.intranetdashboard.com/

Comment: Thanks, do you know about other examples?

Comment: Maybe this could help you: https://www.claromentis.com/intranet-platform/intranet-gallery/ http://www.nngroup.com/articles/intranet-design/ http://pt.slideshare.net/rebeccarodgers/what-a-modern-intranet-home-page-looks-like Hope it could be useful =)

Answer (score 0):

A textbook name I've met for these type of systems is "Knowledge Management Information Systems".